# Creating log file for each request in spring boot using logback xml file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, logback

With respect to my spring boot app below is my logback spring xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration>
<configuration>

    <springProperty scope="context" name="app_name" source="spring.application.name"/>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="environment" source="param_env" defaultValue="default_env"/>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="tenant" source="param_tenant" defaultValue="default_tenant"/>

    <property name="GENERIC_PATTERN"
              value="[%date{ISO8601}] [%p] [%t] [%c{2}] %4L | %m%n"/>
    <property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN" value="$GENERIC_PATTERN"/>
    <property name="CHARSET" value="UTF-8"/>

    <property name="LOG_DIR"
              value="logs/${tenantname:-${tenant}}/${envname:-${environment}}/${param_gslogname:-${app_name}}"/>

    <logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="org.gs" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="com.gs" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="liquibase" level="FINE"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor"
            level="INFO"/>

    <logger name="org.springframework.security" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="org.hibernate" level="INFO"/>

    <!-- Auto configuration report-->
    <logger name="org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener"
            level="TRACE"/>

    <springProfile name="local,component-test,component-test-security,scheduler-test">

        <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <encoder>
                <charset>${CHARSET}</charset>
                <pattern>${GENERIC_PATTERN}</pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>

        <logger name="zuul.web.request.logger" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </logger>

        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </root>

    </springProfile>

    <!-- logging configuration for NOT LOCAL profile -->
    <springProfile name="local, dev, test, uat, preprod, prod, perf">
        <appender name="FILE-THREAD" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
        <!-- This is MDC value -->
        <!-- We will assign a value to 'logFileName' via Java code -->
        <discriminator>
            <key>logFileName</key>
            <defaultValue>head0</defaultValue>
        </discriminator>

        <sift>
            <!-- A standard RollingFileAppender, the log file is based on 'logFileName' at runtime  -->
            <appender name="FILE-${logFileName}"
                      class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
                <file>/Users/${logFileName}.log</file>

                <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
                    <Pattern>
                        %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %mdc [%thread] %level %logger{35} - %msg%n
                    </Pattern>
                </encoder>

                <rollingPolicy
                        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
                    <FileNamePattern>/Users/${logFileName}.%i.log.zip
                    </FileNamePattern>
                    <MinIndex>1</MinIndex>
                    <MaxIndex>10</MaxIndex>
                </rollingPolicy>

                <triggeringPolicy
                        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
                    <MaxFileSize>10MB</MaxFileSize>
                </triggeringPolicy>

            </appender>

 
        <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                <Pattern>
                    %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
                </Pattern>
            </layout>
        </appender>

        <logger name="com.dt.rdk.factory.data.deploy" level="debug"
                additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE-THREAD" />
            <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        </logger>

        <root level="error">
            <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        </root>
        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
            <appender-ref ref="FILE-THREAD"/>
 
        </root>

    </springProfile>
</configuration>
```

And below is the tried approach that I have implemented to create the log file per thread so I am considering this same as creating log file for every request since these are similar so.

below is my code which I have implemented :

```
public class Head implements Runnable {

    static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Head.class);

    private String name;
    
    @Override
    public void run() {

        MDC.put("logFileName", getName());

        logger.info("batch get request recieved");

        //remember remove this
        MDC.remove("logFileName");

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

```
public class DataApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DataApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner applicationRunner(
    ) {
        ThreadPoolExecutor threadPools = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        int count = 1;
        while(count<=10){
            Head head = new Head();
            head.setName("head-" + count);
            threadPools.execute(head);
            count++;
        }
        return args -> {
             
            System.out.println("something");


        };
    }
}
```

I am able to generate the log file for each thread as shown below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTIGl.png)

I have tried this approach to generate the file and I am sure with this we can generate file for each request as well with the help of descriminator

but

**my issue is how will I be able to put lot of logs messages inside these log files for each request? Since my application has lot of logs messages, so any good approach to implement this ?**

Also my issue is how can I put multiple descriminator for implementing this

I was wondering how would I be able to transfer the logs between logback and the java code more frequently that too with creating logs for each new request and for old request it should write to same old log only.

```
  <discriminator>
            <key>logFileName</key>
            <defaultValue>head0</defaultValue>
  </discriminator>
```

Any example or github code would be highly appreciated.

thank you so much

Comment: What is the reason to create a separate log file for each request that is rather strange?

Comment: There is not need to creating a log for each request. Add a request id that is only for each  request . By request id you can filter logs that belong specify request.

Comment: Reason behind this is to generate 1 log file for each batch that we are going to process with one request.